# Liferay integration with cas to provide cross domain SSO

Tags: liferay, single-sign-on, cas

Can anyone verify that `liferay` supports `CAS` for cross domain `SSO`? Or any suggestion for cross domain SSO ?

Answer (score 2):

CAS uses a ticket based form of authentication that supports cross domain SSO.

The client application redirects to the CAS server and upon initial, or verification of, authentication the browser is redirected to the original/client server with a ticket appended to the URL. The client application takes the ticket and itself connects to the CAS server to retrieve the credentials. It can then start an authenticated session for the user.

As long as the url/domain is permitted in the CAS Service Registry, CAS is more than happy to authenticate the client application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,Liferay supports CAS SSO. You can find more information here: [Liferay 6 CAS integration](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/CAS+Liferay+6+Integration?_36_pageResourcePrimKey=6852237)

Comment: My question was if CAS supports cross domain sso (CDSSO) not single domain sso?